# Secure Redirect URLS + Survey Monkey

Tags: javascript, node.js, surveymonkey

I am using survey monkey to allow users to ask users several questions. If they answer the form, they get upgraded to "premium" and are redirected back to the site. There is no code that survey monkey returns that allows me to know that the user actually submitted the form and is not accessing the redirect URL directly. How can I get around this security wise? I want to make sure the user actually submitted the form to qualify for premium. I'm using node.js on the server side and javascript on the client side.

Comment: sounds like a case of "if the tool doesn't work, don't use it". If survey monkey does not give you a completion token of any sort, don't use survey monkey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the prettiest solution, but a quick way I noticed that could be possible from the help center is to [disqualify respondents](http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Disqualifying-Respondents#Option). This is because you can set a custom URL to send the user to after you disqualify them which I don't know if you can otherwise.

You can use [advanced branching logic](http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Advanced-Branching-Rules) to specify when to disqualify the respondent (example, when the last question is answered). You can also use [webhooks](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#webhooks) through the API to get notifications on respondent completions and you can make changes on your end (such as upgrading their plan) using that.

That's one suggestion, you may want to investigate the [help center](http://help.surveymonkey.com/) if that doesn't work for you.